# React PureComponent is updating when it shouldn't be

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently using, in my application, a PureComponent parent and children components. I expected a PureComponent to only update if it's state or props change. To ensure this, I had a child component log something everytime its componentDidUpdate() method was called. The application looks something like this:

```
class Parent extends React.PureComponent{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            item1: null,
            item2: null,
            list1: [],
            list2: [],
        }

    render(){
        let combinedList= [...this.state.list1, ...this.state.list2];

        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <Child myList={combinedList} />
                <OtherChild item={this.state.item1} />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
```

The Child component looks something like this:

```
class Child extends React.PureComponent{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        console.log("Child updated");
    }

    render(){
        return(
            ....
        );
    }
```

For example, when the state of item2 in Parent component changes, the Child component will log "Child updated". I'm a bit confused, since the child component doesn't receive item1 as a prop, and it's state isn't changed. Is this happening because the Parent component rerenders all of it's children? Or maybe because the shallow comparison Child does for its `myList` prop indicate that it has changed? Aside from writing my own `shouldComponentUpdate()` method, how can I prevent Child from rerendering everytime Parent rerenders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now, in your `render` function for the `Parent` component, you're creating a new Array on every render with `combinedList`. PureComponent switches your `shouldComponentUpdate()` method to do a shallow compare to see if it should update. Since it's shallow, it's comparing references.

Since you're creating a new array on every render, it's going to be new every single time the `Parent` renders.

The solution here really depends on the full use-case that you have for `combinedList`. Looking at this example directly, I would recommend that you set `combinedList` in state. The other option would be to split your child component props up into a `list1` and `list2` prop instead of a `myList` prop.

Comment: Ah yea, that's what I was guessing was happening. Darn, ok yea thanks!